# Understanding schema locks in File Geodatabase registered to ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, file-geodatabase, lock

I have a folder containing many File GDBs. I registered this folder with my ArcGIS Server machine. I then published some mxd from ArcMap with data from some of those same fGDBs. The service is working fine and no data is copied to the server (registering worked fine).

I can see many new locks in my fGDBs, and I understand they come from the published active services.

As I can see from [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/25418), locks are of various types:

- RD-Lock - Read Lock
- SR-Lock - Schema Lock
- WR-Lock - Write Lock
- ED-Lock - Edit Lock

Mine are actually SR-Lock type. From ArcMap, I am able to start an edit session on some of the already published data, modify them, and I can see those changes in the service after saving, as expected.

However, I have troubles when it comes to (e.g.) adding a new field. Is this type of operation not allowed when there is a schema lock?

If so, would stopping the service be enough to release the schema lock, performing the changes, overwriting the data and activating it again?

The reason why I am asking is to understand if this is the right way to proceed, as last time I tried, I think I messed up something and I received an error during publishing (Staging the service succeeded, but uploading it did not).

Comment: Sometimes the dataset gets corrupted by publishing failures, and remaindered locks would be among the most common failures.  If you're ***really*** sure the lock is not active, you can try to delete it.  Trying to modify the schema while data is actively being served is a recipe for disaster (which is why locks exist).

Comment: @Vince Thanks. So I guess the way to proceed is correct: if the fGDB is registered with the server, and a process (a map service) is connecting to it generating a sr. Lock, I first have to stop that map service to release that lock, perform my schema changes (e.g. adding a new field to a feature class), overwrite the service, and finally re-activate it? Just to add one more thing. The publishing failure somehow caused my map service being unstoppable/undeleteable from nor ArcMap neither AGS Manager, unless a restart of the AGS Server was performed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from my experience, stopping the service will drop the connection to the database. This usually works with any type of spatial database. However, from my experience, SDE usually works better.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I could still see an sr.lock on the _gdb file inside the gdb. It is like stopping the map service did remove the sr.lock from the feature classes, leaving it at the GDB level. Maybe that was still causing troubles. From [this thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/78554) it seems it is possible, and that you have to manually delete it (which is not that good, considering that ["Changes to the dataset schema (...) may leave your map services in an inconsistent state"](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/disabling-schema-locking-on-a-map-service.htm)).